# Coding Convention Conversion

Tags: code-golf, string

In that Coding Golf, you should convert one coding convention with TitleCase to lower_case_with_underscores. And... vice versa!

## Specification

Change the casing in a following way:

- If underscore character is a delimiter, change the casing to Title Case without any of delimiter.
- If there are multiple words with no delimiter, change the casing to lower case and add an underscore character as a delimiter.
- In case of only one word (or one character): change the casing to Title Case if the word starts with lower case; change the casing to lower case if the word starts with the upper case.

Allowed characters:

- A to Z
- a to z
- underscore (`_`).

Input with mixed cased words are disallowed. Examples of disallowed cases:

- `Coding_Convention_Conversion`
- `a_BC`

## Example Cases

```
Input                        | Expected Output
===========================================================
CodingConventionConversion   | coding_convention_conversion
coding_convention_conversion | CodingConventionConversion
abc                          | Abc
Abc                          | abc
ABC                          | a_b_c
a_b_c                        | ABC
a                            | A
A                            | a
```

## Rules

- It is allowed to use `ToUpper`, `ToLower` and `ToTitleCase` functions.
- Using regular expressions is allowed.
- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Is using a `ToTitleCase` function okay? You didn't specify, so I'd assume it is okay.

Comment: @Justin: Good question indeed. Let's make it more fun and disallow the ToTitleCase function :)

Comment: Darn... my solution relies on it

Comment: @Justin: Okay - I didn't specify it in the beginning, so in that case - let's allow it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 25 bytes <s>29 33 35 40</s>

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Dennis*

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @FryAmTheEggman*

```
?rIz0smrd4cz\_tsXzrG1*\_G
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3FrIz0smrd4cz%5C_tsXzrG1%2a%5C_G&input=CodingConventionConversion&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=CodingConventionConversion%0Acoding_convention_conversion%0Aabc%0Aa_b_c%0AABC&debug=0)

Comment: Your link needs to be updated.

Comment: When I try put "abc" as an input, it yields "bc" as an output. Bug? :)

Comment: To fix what @DariuszWoźniak noticed, you can change your condition from `/z\_` to `rIz0`. I also believe I found a same-length alternative to the adding underscores program: `tsXzrG1_Mcj\_G2`, maybe someone can golf it more...

Comment: Ah, found it: `tsXzrG1*\_G`

Answer (score 8):

## Jolf, 35 bytes

*Saves 1 byte thanks to @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ*. This is encoded in ISO 8859-7.

```
? hI'_ΜGI'_dpyH0pxRGIL0"(?=[A-Z])'_
```

Woohoo my first Jolf program!

### Explanation

```
   // I = input
? hI'_                              // If input contains _
       GI'_                          // Split on _
      Μ    d                         // Loop, then join
            pyH0                     // Make the first character uppercase
                                    // ELSE...
                  RGIL0"(?=[A-Z])    // Split *after* all uppercase chars
                                 '_  // join with _ 
                px                   //Make lowercase
```

[Try it online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=PyBoSSdfEM6cR0knX2RweUgwcHhSR0lMMCIoPz1bQS1aXSknXw)

Comment: You can use string separation at the end, so it becomes `"(?=[A-Z])'_`. The string is closed automatically.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ oh, cool, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 37

Thanks to @ MartinBüttner for saving 4 bytes!

```
^|[A-Z]
_$0
T`Ll`lL`_.
^_|_(?=[A-Z])
```

(Note the trailing newline.)

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBefFtBLVpdCl8kMApUYExsYGxMYF8uCm1gXl98Xyg_PVtBLVpdKQo&input=Q29kaW5nQ29udmVudGlvbkNvbnZlcnNpb24KY29kaW5nX2NvbnZlbnRpb25fY29udmVyc2lvbgphYmMKQWJjCkFCQwphX2JfYwphCkE)  Note this includes extra `` m` ``  to configure a couple of lines to treat each input line separately so all testcases may be run in one go.  This is not a requirement of the question, so these are not counted in the score.

- Lines 1 and 2 insert `_` either at the beginning of input or before uppercase letters.  All words are now `_`-separated, regardless of case.
- Line 3 swaps case of the first letter in each word.
- Lines 4 and 5 remove `_` either at the start of input, or when followed by an uppercase letter.

Comment: This saves four bytes: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=bWBefFtBLVpdCl8kMApUYExsYGxMYF8uCm1gXl98Xyg_PVtBLVpdKQo&input=Q29kaW5nQ29udmVudGlvbkNvbnZlcnNpb24KY29kaW5nX2NvbnZlbnRpb25fY29udmVyc2lvbgphYmMKQWJjCkFCQwphX2JfYwphCkE

Comment: Also you can avoid the trailing empty line by omitting the last `?=` and replacing that stage with `$1` (doesn't affect the byte count though).

Comment: @Martin Very good - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## GNU Sed, 46

Thanks to @TobySpeight for saving 2 bytes!

Score includes +1 for `-E` (or `-r`) option to `sed`.

```
s/(^|_)([a-z])/\u\2/g
t
s/[A-Z]/_\l&/g
s/^_//
```

[Try it online.](https://ideone.com/MqSbzl)

Fairly straightforward sed:

- Line 1 substitutes beginning of line or `_`, followed by a lowercase letter with the upper case of that letter.  The `g` flag to `s` performs this substitution for each instance found
- `t` jumps to the `:` unnamed label if there were any matches for the above substitution.  This label is implicitly at the end.
- Otherwise all uppercase letters are substituted with `_` the lower case of that letter
- This leaves a leading `_` before the first letter.  `s/^_//` removes that.

Comment: @Toby Thanks.  `-E` works in my GNU sed 4.2.2 (Ubuntu 14.04.3), though its not in the man page.  I read somewhere [citation needed] that `-E` is newer Posix option that will officially be added to GNU Sed in a newer release, but is already there unofficially.  Regardless, `-r` does the right thing if `-E` doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Toby [lines 280-282 of sed/sed.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/snapshot/sed-4.2.2.tar.gz) are `/* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */` `case 'E':` `case 'r':`.

Comment: @Digital - I was mistaken; my sed _does_ accept `-E` as a synonym for `-r`.  I wasn't correctly passing a minimal program e.g. `sed -E -e Q`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]|(^|_)(.)/g,(c,_,l,i)=>l?l.toUpperCase():(i?"_":"")+c.toLowerCase())
```

### Explanation

Depending on which part of the regex matched, it replaces the match with the opposite case.

```js
s.replace(
  /[A-Z]|(^|_)(.)/g,
  (c,_,l,i)=>
    l?
      (i?"_":"")+c.toLowerCase()
    :l.toUpperCase()
)
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]|(^|_)(.)/g,(c,_,l,i)=>l?l.toUpperCase():(i?"_":"")+c.toLowerCase())
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="coding_convention_conversion" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP 160 bytes

not the shortest but for completeness here my solution in PHP, $s holds the string to convert:

```
trim(preg_replace_callback('/((^[a-z]|_[a-z])|([A-Z]))/',function($m){return empty($m[2])?'_'.strtolower($m[3]):strtoupper(str_replace('_','',$m[2]));},$s),'_')
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf Stack Exchange. Well done for posting something in a language that you knew wasn't going to win. [tag:code-golf] challenges are mostly within languages, so using a non-golfing language is good. +1 d:-D

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>101</s> <s>87</s> 75 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub(/^.|[A-Z]/,'_\0').gsub(/_./,&:swapcase).gsub(/_(?=[A-Z])|^_/,'')}
```

Unfortunately, this does exactly the same thing as the Retina solution, as that method ended up being shorter than anything else I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 130 bytes

Quick and dirty attempt using regex to split at the caps. Pretty brute force: if anyone can come up with a different approach I'm sure this can be beaten.

```python
import re
lambda s:('_'.join(re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',s)).lower(),''.join([a[0].upper()+a[1:]for a in s.split('_')]))[s.islower()]
```

Answer (score 2):

## 3, 15 chars / 32 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
⟮ѨǱï⟯≠ï?Ⅰ:ѨȎѨƎï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=CodingConventionConversion&code=%E2%9F%AE%D1%A8%C7%B1%C3%AF%E2%9F%AF%E2%89%A0%C3%AF%3F%E2%85%A0%3A%D1%A8%C8%8E%D1%A8%C6%8E%C3%AF)</kbd>

v3 was released after this challenge, with a bunch of bugfixes and library updates.

## Explanation

This is just a mashup of builtins.

```
⟮ѨǱï⟯≠ï?Ⅰ:ѨȎѨƎï // implicit: ï=input
⟮ѨǱï⟯≠ï?        // check if ï is NOT in snake_case
       Ⅰ       // if so, then convert to snake_case
        :ѨȎѨƎï // otherwise, convert to camelCase and make the first letter UPPERCASE
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
e€ØAḊkŒlj”_$ʋ⁾_ yŒtḲƲ}Ẹ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzMcH@7oyj46KSfrUcPceJVT3Y8a98UrVB6dVPJwx6Zjm2of7tph/9/6UcMcBV07BaAS68PtXIfbgToj//9Xcs5PycxLd87PK0vNK8nMzwOzioqBLCUdpWSwZHwyXBbChEnnJeamAik/EAUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
lambda s,u='_':''.join([u[i>u:]+i.lower()for i in(s<u)*s]or[u]+s.title().split(u))[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc1NCsIwEAXgfU4x0MUkKgVxV1TQHqOWktZWR2pS8qN4@hojuKvNJg/m473h5a5abcZudxp7ea/PEuzK77DCDDG9aVK88AXtfVYuKe31szVcdNoAQTjZrRcLW2pT@HJpU0eub7lI7dCT416IYp2V40fboIEzzPWZ1CXX6tEqR1rFZGxIuAKABJoIquYnvjEShv@uoSCB6X6Gsm7iyMRL4FA3DA9zSkZ1zGdUVVfBxW9ahs1jHtS/rqjC4pyRTGQwGFKOd9wKMb4B)

Also [works in Python 2](https://tio.run/##hc1NCsIwEAXgfU4x0MUkKgVdFhW0x6ilpLXVkZqU/CievsYI7mqzyYP5eG94uatWm7HbncZe3uuzBLvyO6wwQ0xvmhQvfEF7n5VLSnv9bA0XnTZAEE5268XCltoUvlza1JHrWy5SO/TkuBeiWGfl@NE2aOAMc30mdcm1erTKkVYxGRsSrgAggSaCqvmJb4yE4b9rKEhgup@hrJs4MvESONQNw8OcklEd8xlV1VVw8ZuWYfOYB/WvK6qwOGckExkMhpTjHbdCjG8).

Making use of the convenient fact that the ascii value for `_` (95) is right in between those of the uppercase (65-90) and lowercase (97-122) letters, which allows for easy string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>73 72 71</s>  68 bytes

```perl6
{.comb(/<:Lu><:Ll>*|<:Ll>+/).map({/<:Lu>/??.lc!!.tc}).join('_'x?/<:Lu>/)} # 73
{.comb(/<:Lu><:Ll>*|<:L>+/).map({/<:Lu>/??.lc!!.tc}).join('_'x?/<:Lu>/)}  # 72
{/<:Lu>/??S:g/(^)?(<:Lu>)/{$0||'_'}$1.lc()/!!S:g/[^|_](<:Ll>)/$0.tc()/}   # 71
{.comb(/<:Lu><:Ll>*|<:L>+/).map({/<:Lu>/??.lc!!.tc}).join('_'x!/_/)}      # 68
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &code = {...}

for <CodingConventionConversion coding_convention_conversion abc Abc ABC a_b_c a A>
{ say .&code }
```

```
coding_convention_conversion
CodingConventionConversion
Abc
abc
a_b_c
ABC
A
a
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{
  .comb( / <:Lu><:Ll>* | <:L>+ / ) # grab the "words" only
  .map({
      /<:Lu>/ # if the word has uppercase
    ??
      .lc     # lowercase the whole word
    !!
      .tc     # otherwise titlecase the word
   })
  .join(  # join the words
    '_'   # with '_'
    x     # repeated
    !/_/  # zero times if it had a _, otherwise once
  )
}
```

You may be wondering why I used the Unicode properties (`<:Lu>`, `<:Ll>`) instead of just a character class. 
In [Perl 6](http://perl6.org) they are no longer spelled `[a-z]` they are spelled `<[a..z]>` which is 1.6 times as big.
The brackets `[ … ]` are used for non-capturing grouping instead which was spelled as `(?: … )` in Perl 5.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 40 bytes

```
UfV="%A" ?UrV@'_s!Y +Xv} :Ur"^.|_."_sJ u
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VWZWPSIlQSIgP1VyVkAnX3MhWSArWHZ9IDpVciJeLnxfLiJfc0ogdQ==&input=ImFfYl9jIg==)

## How it works

```
           // Implicit: U = input string
UfV="%A"   // Set variable V to the string "\\A", and get all matches in U.
?          // If the list is not null:
UrV@     } //  Replace each match X and its index Y with this function:
'_s!Y +Xv  //   Return "_".slice(!Y) (1 for Y=0, 0 for anything else) + X.toLowerCase().
:          // Otherwise:
Ur"^.|_."  //  Replace the char at the beginning and each char following an underscore with:
_sJ u      //   The last char of the match (the letter) .toUpperCase().
```

Comment: Why is the `U` not automatically inserted?

Comment: @SamuelWaller, because this solution pre-dates that feature being added.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 42 bytes

40 bytes plus 2 for `-p` (thanks, [dev-null](/u/48657))

```
s/[A-Z]/_\l$&/g||s/(^|_)(.)/\u$2/g;s/_//
```

Comment: On Windows, using perl and MINGW32, I get no output, what am I missing?

Comment: @ChatterOne I don't know what MINGW32 is, but it worked fine for me on Strawberry Perl. Use `-E` instead of `-e`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 129 bytes

```forth
: f bounds dup c@ 32 xor emit 1+ ?do i c@ '_ < if ." _"i c@ 32 + emit then i c@ '_ > if i 1- c@ '_ = 32 * i c@ + emit then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5NDoIwEAXgvad4YWMiwUTcGFH84SANlIJNtNPQavT0SAsaN6LddKb9Mm8qauwpqit3te0aFQq6qtKgvGrwPZYx7tRAXKTFIsSuJEj3PmXYQFaYB2CBHGTYO3sS6q1SpyQW0dBvHZz135/@TKSRdBtoxC7bPrTwS8QrRMgLA6NzLoxLRJQi6FblDZKJCZBRKVWdkboJZSUpXzWmqzoL7Qj3hPG36csBeZIX3PEvx5PDH@SY/SI5K9j3OT0ZmfEKGiftEw)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f              \ start a new word definition
  bounds         \ convert string address and length to beginning and ending address
  dup c@         \ get the first character
  32 xor emit    \ convert to the opposite case and output
  1+             \ add 1 to beginning of string (skip starting char)
  ?do            \ begin counted loop over string character addresses
    i c@ '_ <    \ check if char is uppercase 
    if           \ if it is:
      ." _"      \ output underscore
      i c@       \ get current char
      32 + emit  \ convert to lowercase and output
    then         \ end if block
    i c@ '_ >    \ check if lowercase (not '_')
    if           \ if it is:
      i 1- c@    \ get the previous character
      '_ = 32 *  \ if it's an underscore, multiply by 32 (true = -1 in forth)
      i c@ +     \ add result to current char (make uppercase if previous was '_')
      emit       \ output resulting char
    then         \ end if block
  loop           \ end loop
;                \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 37 bytes

```
'_Na?UC@_.@>_Ma^'_(LC_MRXU.XL.'+a)J'_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fPd4v0T7U2SFez8Eu3jcxTj1ew8c53jcoIlQvwkdPXTtR00s9/v///875KZl56c75eWWpeSWZ@XlgVlExkAUA)

Lot of underscores in this one.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 43 bytes

```
{("_"/(&x<_x)__x;,/`c$t-32*~<'t:"_"\x)x~_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYnRCoJAEEX/ZYjaLUWwN9cX298IJl1TRJgFW2Ig8te3UbGXw7n3jCn1FGNXfBQgZOrIJbJGZJNkD3cI6TU/z@UpFFLvrHlG/saLCqaTT4H17UC99fR@Uhg8rTa9xMCAWyO6f910z3XjhNXGm10ebFBWAvWCCrSOPw)

- `x~_x` check if the input `x` is all lowercase
- `(...;...)` index into this two-item list depending on that value (i.e., return the first item in the list if `x` contains an uppercase letter, and the second item if it does not)
- When `x` contains an uppercase letter:

  - `(&x<_x)` identify indices of uppercase letters
  - `(...)__x` split the lowercased input on those indices
  - `"_"/` join the resulting chunks with underscores
- When `x` is all lowercase:

  - `t:"_"\x` split input on underscores, storing in variable `t`
  - `t-32*~<'t` capitalize the first letter in each chunk (this converts to integers)
  - `` ,/`c$ `` convert back to characters, flattening the list

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 37 bytes

```
a'_ Ä?Uq'_ ®hZu g} q:Uò@Yc <#a} q'_ v
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YSdfIMQ/VXEnXyCuaFp1IGd9IHE6VfJAWWMgPCNhfSBxJ18gdg==&input=WyJIZWxsb1RoZXJlIiwKImhlbGxvX3RoZXJlIl0KLW0=)

Explanation:

```
There are some unicode chars that a shortcuts for common groups of chars,
like Ä is +1. This is the expanded version.

     // U = input string
a'_  // get index of "_" in string, -1 if not found
+1   // add 1 to make -1 falsy
?    // if truthy, ie. if there is an underscore in the input text
Uq'_ // split on underscores
m_   // map
h    // replace character (first char by default)
Zu g // the first letter of the string converted to uppercase (Zug)
} q  // close function and join
:    // else, ie. the string doesn't have any underscores
Uò   // runs func on every pair of chars, splits them if it returns true
@Yc <#a } // returns true if the second char code is less than "a", ie. uppercase
q'_  // join with underscores
v    // make lowercase

implicit print
```

First Japt program, I beat the creator, and Zu g!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>27</s> 26 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I fear I may have gone in the wrong direction with this; stuck on 27 and can't seem to do any better.

```
r"^.|_.|%A"ÈÌc^H i'_pY©XÊu
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciJeLnxfLnwlQSLIzGNeSCBpJ19wWalYynU&input=WwoiQ29kaW5nQ29udmVudGlvbkNvbnZlcnNpb24iCiJjb2RpbmdfY29udmVudGlvbl9jb252ZXJzaW9uIgoiIgoiYWJjIgoiQWJjIgoiIgoiQUJDIgoiYV9iX2MiCiIiCiJhIgoiQSIKXQotbVI)

```
r"^.|_.|%A"ÈÌc^H i'_pY©XÊu     :Implicit input of string
r                              :Replace
 "^.|_.|%A"                    :RegEx /^.|_.|[A-Z]/g
           È                   :Pass each match X at 0-based index Y through the following function
            Ì                  :  Last character of X
             c                 :  Charcode
              ^H               :  Bitwise XOR with 32
                 i             :  Prepend
                  '_p          :    "_" repeated
                     Y©        :      Logical AND of Y and
                       XÊ      :      Length of X
                         u     :      Mod 2
```