# snakes_are_bad, camelsAreBetter

Tags: code-golf, string

## Introduction

All these snakes everywhere! I've had enough, and have decided that I much prefer camels. Therefore, I want you to convert my snakes to camels for me.

## Challenge

Turn any `snake_case` string into a `camelCase` string. 
Capitals should be returned to lowercase before the conversion occurs.

## Test Cases

In: `camel_case` 
Out: `camelCase`

In: `curse_these_snakes` 
Out: `curseTheseSnakes`

In: `i_promise_1234_is_not_my_password` 
Out: `iPromise1234IsNotMyPassword`

In: `AAAAA_BBBBB` 
Out: `aaaaaBbbbb`

## Rules

As per usual, standard [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1789#1789) apply. 
This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - shortest answer wins.
Leading/trailing underscores (e.g `_string_`) are ignored.

## Current Winners (subject to change)

### Esoteric Language

Me, with -1 bytes.

### Standard Language

Also me, with -2 bytes.

Comment: What about strings starting with an underscore? eg. `_a`

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/70180/87681)

Comment: Hm. My research couldn't seem to find that, so I apologise - should I remove the question?

Comment: Similar but not the same in my opinion.. Here we have only snake to camel, and not tile convention at all, e.g. The first word is lower case.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda s:s[0].lower()+s.title().replace('_','')[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYrLDoIwEEX3foW7ttE0Iq5IXOhvIJmMMITGvtKpIXx9hZXhLO7inBuXPAVfl/H@Khbde8AjN9xeOm3DTEmqE@tssiWpdKJosScpQJyFUG3VdCUm47McpejRkYUemYRSh7/@JibIE63LHj/Eu2wgpuDMGqtrfQPD4EMGt0BE5jmkYfd@bMBzY/XlBw)

*-4 bytes thanks to [ReinstateMonica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85755/reinstate-monica)*

Comment: Unless it introduces some edge case I'm not seeing, [replace is shorter](https://tio.run/##VYrLDoIwEEX3fgW7ttEQEVckLvA3kExGGEJjX@nUEL6@wspwFmdxzw1rmr2r8/R4ZYP2PWLBDXfXvjR@oSjVmcukkyGpykjB4EBSgLgIobqq6XOI2iU5STGgJQMDMhVCqdN//0YmSDNtZocf4mPXEKK3eqvVrb6DZnA@gV0hIPPi43i8tzvw3NlD/gE "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @ReinstateMonica yep, fair.

Comment: Trailing underscores are removed. In case of leading underscore next char is removed.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYrLDoIwEEX3foW7ttEQEVckLvQ3kEwqDKGxr8zUEL6@lp3hLs7inBvXNAff5On@yla796iP3HJ36SsbFiSpTlwlkyxKVRFGqweUAsRZCNXVbZ8jGZ/kVNygHdpCRhBKHf7Cl4pLMxay1x/k3cFApOBMyfW1uYFh8CGBWyFq5iXQuPs/tsFzWwn5Bw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Thanks, but a leading underscore is not valid `snake_case` input, so there's no need to handle it.

Comment: @Jitse  Leading and trailing underscores are mentioned in the text of the challenge. And your code process both of them incorrectly.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg This really very much depends on how you define 'ignored'. Since this challenge is already closed as a duplicate, I will leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->x{x.downcase.gsub(/_(.)/){$1.upcase}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYq9DoIwFEZ3n6IhDu1gCeqqCb7ITSlFG/uXXhoghGevdJMzfMM5X0zdkgfyIPnynNeZ935yUqDib0wdrYFyVrP13PAUit62HMjApTCGVlJYZaDoip3@dIqoYPyofdGJr8JD1hCit3qPzfV2B43g/Ah2gSAQJx/7w7stwKtQsfwD)

This does nothing to leading and trailing underscores.

Comment: Trailing underscore is removed by this code.

Comment: Is it? It's not for me. [Here](https://tio.run/##VYqxDoMgFEX3fgUxHWAoxrZrm9gfeUHElhSE8CRqjN9OYatnuMM5N8RuTQN5kHR5LtvCezePUqDib4wdrYFyVrPt3PDoi9735MnApTCGVlJYZaBoqNjpz8eQ1fRReXEUX4XHrsEHZ3WuzfV2B40wugnsCl4gzi70x3tbgFchh/QD "Ruby – Try It Online")'s a Try-It-Online where they all have trailing underscores. And they're not removed.

Comment: Sorry for mistype. Leading underscores are removed.

Comment: Also capitalisation is changed in case of leading underscore.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYq9DoIwFEZ3n6IhDu1gCeqqCb7ITSlFG/uXXhoghGevdJMzfMM5X0zdkgfyIPnynNeZ935yUqDib0wdrYFyVrP13PAUit62HMjApTCGViCFVQaKr9jp36eICsaP2hed@Co8dg0heqv32lxvd9AIzo9gFwgCcfKxP97bArwKFcs/ "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 28 characters

```
_?=@upcase{?}
?=@downcase{?}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ gema '_?=@upcase{?};?=@downcase{?}' <<< 'i_promise_1234_is_not_my_password'
iPromise1234IsNotMyPassword
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LchJCoAwEETRfW7jsBWHixRNbDRoBtKKiHj2mIB/UfBqYUspoe@GM2gSfvpXZcz@cj9T0mR5R6HSZxTGsXJecbSxKIMQvTX5qOqmhRE4f8DeCCRy@TirsYSp9AE)